# How i can convert datetime to unix time stamp and compare it with other timestamp in php?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, unix

I have one page in that I have two textboxes where user will enter unix timestamp and datetime, I have to compare that both timestamp and datetime but in php the timezone giving different timestamp as per time zone so the code doesn't working in all places where time zones are different.

Please help on this I had used..

```
strtotime(),mktime(),getTimestamp()
```

in php,

also used my sql for this..

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
```

but all are giving different time stamps.

```
$sql = "SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('date time from text box') as timeStampfromdb";
            $result = mysql_query($sql);
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
                $timeStampFromDateTime = $row["timeStampfromdb"];
            }           
            if($timeStampFromDateTime == timestamp textbox value)
            {
                matched
            }
            else
            {
                not matched
            }
```

Comment: Please post your code. The unix timestamp has nothing to do with time zones.

Comment: @bartimar thanks for reply..if that has nothing to do with timezone then why mysql database in india giving 8 hrs diffrence in datetime while executing same query SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP() in america giving 8 hrs diff.. bcoz it has -8GMT in pacific

Comment: Whether or not there will be a difference depends on how the servers are configured. If time zones are a concern make sure both servers are using GMT and you will avoid time zone differences and issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set php [timezone](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) in php.ini file, for GMT you need "GMT".

You can also try in your code:

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s T', time()) . "<br>\n";
date_default_timezone_set('GMT');
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s T', time()) . "<br>\n";
```

time() should return the current unix timestamp.

Comment: Thanks for your answer..@Tal Kitron.. your solution will help me to solve my pro..

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with dates and times across time zones you should work with everything in GMT to avoid time zone issues. If you need to display a date and time at some point that is the place to do any time zone conversion that may be necessary.